# VMware ESXi QueryDateTime() Method Example

Tags: c#, esxi

I am trying to write an applicaiton that will run as a scheduled task on the vCenter server and will monitor the current time of each host in my cluster. The time is set by NTP but I am seeing VM servers running on these hosts going out by up to a minute and need to monitor what happens.

My hosts are running ESXi v5.1

According to the documentation (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.DateTimeSystem.html#queryDateTime) there is a method that gets the current DateTime of a host - `QueryDateTime()`.

I am struggling to get this to work though.... my sample code is below. It always complains about the `QueryDateTime` method not existing!

This is likely me not understanding the SDK, but I can't figure this out.....

```
VimClient vimClient = new VimClient();
vimClient.Connect(vcenter.ServiceURL);
vimClient.Login(vcenter.Username, vcenter.Password); 

List<EntityViewBase> hosts = vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(VMware.Vim.HostSystem), null, null, null);

foreach (HostSystem host in hosts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(host.Config.Network.Vnic[0].Spec.Ip.IpAddress);

    HostConfigManager hostConfigManager = host.ConfigManager;

    HostDateTimeSystem hostDateTimeSystem = hostConfigManager.DateTimeSystem;

    DateTime hostDateTime = hostDateTimeSystem.QueryDateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
foreach (HostSystem host in vmHosts)
{
HostConfigManager hostConfigManager = host.ConfigManager;
HostDateTimeSystem hostDateTimeSystem = (HostDateTimeSystem) vimClient.GetView(hostConfigManager.DateTimeSystem, null));
DateTime hostDateTime = hostDateTimeSystem.QueryDateTime();
}
```